# How to make curved windows using Archimesh?

Tags: modeling, add-on, workflow, archimesh-add-on

[image]I'm on blender 2.83.1, and I'm using the archimesh panel window to model windows because its easy to just stick in.
However for the main bay window of my house (there's 6 windows), when I change the number of windows in archimesh, I have no option to make them in a semi circle like I need for my bay window.

Does anyone know how to use archimesh, because its super easy, and still be able to get my windows going in semi circle for the bay?

Comment: Hello, it would be helpful if you added some images of your scene to your question I think.

Comment: is this image good?

Comment: that cleared it up thanks, see if my answer helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose one to go about this is to simply use modifiers.

Position the *window group* about where it should be, and add a [subdivision surface modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/modeling/modifiers/generate/subsurf.html#subdivision-surface-modifier) set to simple (this will avoid unwanted deformation of the shape and allow the next modifier to work)), followed by [simple deform](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/deform/simple_deform.html#simple-deform-modifier). set to *bend* to the *window object* inside of the window group empty.
[image]

Adjust the angle of the simple deform, and adjust position as needed, and you should end up with something like this result:

[image]

Comment: I have another question related to the windows. Can I continue it on this thread, or do I have to start a new question?

Comment: Please ask a new question, it helps to keep things organized. You may link to this one if it helps provide context. You are welcome to ask as many questions as you need.